# How to generate just a key with openssl

Tags: security, openssl, certificates

I run this command to generate a CSR and a new key with openssl:

```
openssl req -new -nodes -days 9000 -config /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf -out /etc/ssl/certs/mycompany.com.csr -keyout /etc/ssl/private/mycompany.com.key
```

I can't figure out what command I can run to generate just the key and not the CSR?

Comment: Check the man page for openssl. `req` is *PKCS#10 X.509 **Certificate Signing Request (CSR) Management.*** That means that you can't use `req` to work with something other than CSRs. Depending on what you really want to do, commands like `passwd`, `pkey` or `rand` may fit the bill better.

Comment: Thanks, what I want to know is what will produce the exact same kind of key as the `req` above. I think it is something like `openssl genrsa -out /etc/ssl/private/mycompany.com.key 2048`, just not sure?

Comment: @Michael sorry, I should point out that the `req` in the question does produce a key because of the `-keyout` - that might have not been clear enough in the question.

Comment: Thanks for the post. I found many usefull commands to generate csr, key and self-signed crt on the fly with one command in non-interactive mode.
Here is the link - http://sysadm.pp.ua/internet/pound-apache-nginx-ssl-setup.html ,maybe if would be usefull

Comment: @aprogrammer - thanks for the link, the commands on that page are useful, but the rest of the page is in Russian. Here's the Google translated URL for that page: https://translate.google.com/translate?hl=en&sl=ru&tl=en&u=http%3A%2F%2Fsysadm.pp.ua%2Finternet%2Fpound-apache-nginx-ssl-setup.html.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the `genrsa` switch is the key that's getting generated in the `req` command. To generate the key I believe you just need to run this command:

```
$ openssl genrsa -out clientkey.pem
```

I always reference this page titled: [The Most Common OpenSSL Commands - SSL Shopper](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html). You can see from the examples that the key for a CSR is RSA, you can even control it's length when using the `req` command through the `rsa:2048` parameter.

Examples:

- Generate a new private key and Certificate Signing Request

  ```
  $ openssl req -out CSR.csr -new -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout privateKey.key
  ```
- Generate a certificate signing request (CSR) for an existing private key

  ```
  $ openssl req -out CSR.csr -key privateKey.key -new
  ```

In the above you'll notice the use of the `privateKey.key` from the previous step being used to create the CSR.

#### References

- [openssl cheatsheet](http://wiki.samat.org/CheatSheet/OpenSSL)
- [The Most Common OpenSSL Commands - SSL Shopper](http://www.sslshopper.com/article-most-common-openssl-commands.html)

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted to know. I had found that page and noticed that it didn't have a command to generate a standalone key, which I think is a bit odd, don't you?

Comment: @JackDouglas - yes I usually use that page plus several others to "refresh" my memories on how openssl works 8-). I've been meaning to write them up on my blog, when I can find the time.